# Selenium working perfectly in Eclipse but failing when a JAR file is created

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am trying to deploy an application by creating a JAR file from the export option in Eclipse. The application has been tested multiple times on Eclipse and works perfectly in all Java versions -> 11 through 17 JavaSE. However, when a JAR file is created, the application breaks with the following output!

```
   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:rsrc:selenium-server-4.1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:rsrc:slf4j-simple-1.7.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:rsrc:webdrivermanager-5.0.3-fat.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:577)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:198)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:164)
        at rhea.sonarqubeparser.seleniumSonar.automateSonarTokenGeneration(seleniumSonar.java:72)
        at rhea.sonarqubeparser.runningexample.ExampleClass.main(ExampleClass.java:42)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.1.0', revision: '87802e897b'
System info: host: 'kali', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.14.0-kali4-amd64', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:223)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
        ... 12 more
```

I have been trying to solve this issue by running using OpenJDK 17.0.1 to OpenJDK 11 which is present on Kali by default. Would be really great if someone could help me solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Where is your driver binary located? Make sure it's included in your project folder and exported in the jar as well.

Comment: Yup. Did that already before posting here. No luck.